# The gases of technology

Tags: exoplanet

Ask around and find out what gases, vapors, and/or fumes, in the atmosphere are the result of advanced technology. Then use a spectroscopy to look for those compounds in the atmospheres of earth like exo-planets. Who is doing this?

Comment: Given good enough technology, why is there reason to believe there will be any gaseous emissions?

Comment: First do such gases exist in our atmosphere, as a result of technology?

Comment: Carbon dioxide (from combustion of fossil fuels - also could come from completely natural sources) chlorofluorocarbons (CFCs refrigerant, propellant - don't know if there are natural sources) ..

Comment: I was thinking CFC's as wel but what other? Keep open could be certain metal fume or evaporated solvent vapors. They should have a low probability of occurring naturally.

Comment: And they would have to be able to be detectable from ... across the vast extent.

Comment: Does any one know if this is being done.

Comment: *"Who is doing this?"* Given 1) There are other processes in alien atmospheres we do not entirely (know about or) understand. 2) We don't really know what gases other 'technology' is likely to emit  3) Other technologies might not emit any gases. 4) We're really not sure what gases to look for, even for detecting *life* on other planets. - I suspect the answer is 'no one'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson CFC's are definitely a sign of intelligent life, but Carbon dioxide is definitely not.  Keep in mind that Venus and Mars have atmospheres that are primarily made of carbon dioxide.

Comment: @Phiteros *"CFC's are definitely a sign of intelligent life,"* You could argue, conversely, that any life form that lives on a planet with an ozone layer protecting the lifeforms from radiation, isn't very 'intelligent' for dumping CFCs into that atmosphere. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's just semantics.  Also, for the points you bring up, we may not know what gases other technologies will produce, but we do know what gases are not naturally occurring due to geologic processes.  If we find those gases, it's a strong indicator of the presence of life.  If we find gases such as CFC's, which really have no way of being produced by anything other than industry, it's a strong indicator of technologically advanced life.

Comment: @Phiteros *"That's just semantics."* It was just a ***joke.*** O_o

Comment: @AndrewThompson I figured it was likely a joke, but the definitions of "intelligence" and "life" are things that are seriously discussed and debated.

Answer (score 8):

The best method of analyzing exoplanet atmospheres is called [Transit Absorption Spectroscopy](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/extrasol/lectures/spectra/spectra.html).  First, we analyze the spectrum of an exoplanet's star.  Then, we wait for the planet to pass in front of the star.  When it does so, some of the star's light is absorbed by the planet's atmosphere, changing its spectrum.  Analyzing this change will tell us what chemicals are present in the planet's atmosphere.

In order to detect life, there are several compounds which researchers look for.  One of these is Oxygen.  Oxygen is a highly reactive element, and will disappear from a planet's atmosphere very rapidly if it is not being produced anywhere.  Life uses oxygen because it is so reactive, so if oxygen is present in a planet's atmosphere, it is a strong indicator of the presence of life.

In order to look for intelligent, technologically advanced life, researchers search for compounds which are not present in nature.  One of the most notable compounds is the family of chlorofluorocarbons (CFC's).  CFC's have [no known natural source](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v399/n6738/full/399749a0.html), and have a highly noticeable [infrared absorption line](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2041-8205/792/1/L7/meta).

Most of the absorption lines produced by these gases are in the infrared.  This means that you need a special infrared telescope to observe them.  Unfortunately, since our atmosphere is opaque at some of the frequencies required to find CFC's, you need to use space-based telescopes.  There are hopes that the James Webb Space Telescope and the Transit Exoplanet Survey Satellite will be able to do this work [when they launch](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.08922.pdf).  As [this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2041-8205/792/1/L7/meta) shows, the JWST would have to focus on a planet for ~5 hours to determine the atmosphere's composition.

This work can be done [from the ground](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/372/2014/20130083.short), but it is more difficult and has more uncertainty.

More sources:

http://www.astrobio.net/news-exclusive/unintelligent-life-cfcs/

Comment: The above journal article (astro bio news) answered my questions exactly without pause or obfuscation. Thank you Phiteros.